# using a logical expression containing %in% with duplicated function in r

Tags: r

I am dealing with a set of variables that look something like below

```
   IndexA IndexB     
1     A     B 
2     B     A 
3     A     C
```

I would like to remove all duplicates where A is in B and B is in A. So that the resulting dataset looks like this:

```
   IndexA IndexB     
1     A     B 
2     A     C
```

I have managed to obtain a list of all of the duplicates using subsetting e.g.

```
    duplicates<-df[df$IndexA %in% df$IndexB & df$IndexB %in% df$IndexA,]
```

However, I want to be able to retain only one of the duplicates that is returned for each case where df$IndexA %in% df$IndexB & df$IndexB %in% df$IndexA

Comment: Sort rowwise, then remove duplicates?

Comment: You mean manually remove each duplicate? I was after something a bit more automated since the list of duplicates I have is over 200 cases

Comment: Something like: `df1[ !duplicated(t(apply(df1, 1, sort))), ]` ?

Comment: See also the "Linked" questions in the dupe for other alternatives.